# Back-of-the-envelope calculation in a triple-differences

Tags: econometrics

So, I’m getting confused about how to do a simple back-of-the-envelope calculation in a triple differences (DDD) setup.

This is a slightly different DDD. Instead of using two different control groups to "clean" different sets of unobservable characteristics, I'm investigating two different policies that affect different groups of people (policy at the county level), with some intersection.

Let's say population Pa is affected by policy A only; population Pb is affected by policy B only; population Pab is affected by both policies; and population P0 is affected by none.

My outcome is given in rate, say number of crimes per inhabitants.

My unit of observation is a county by year.

A simplified version of the model is as follows, where $T^a_{it}$ is an indicative variable equals 1 if policy A is implemented in county $i$ at year $t$, and the same goes for $T^b_{it}$.

$cr_{it}$ = $\beta_a$ $T^{a}_{it}$ + $\beta_b$ $T^{b}_{it}$ +$\beta_{ab}$ $T^{a}_{it}$ $T^{b}_{it}$ + $\epsilon_{it}$

I run my DDD and I get the coefficients $\beta_a$, $\beta_b$, $\beta_{ab}$.

I want to tell (roughly) how did criminality declined because of these policies.
So, my doubt about back-of-the-envelope calculation is:

The effect of these policies on crime is a yearly variation in crime that equals:

Option 1)     $B_a$*(Pa) + $B_b$*(Pb) + $B_ab$*(Pab)

or equals:

Option 2)     $B_a$*(Pa+Pab) + $B_b$*(Pb+Pab) + $B_ab$*(Pab)

Also, how can I find the effect of policy A alone?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Why not run a model with dummies for Policy A only, Policy B only, and Policy A+B group (with untreated as the omitted category), post dummies for Policy A, B, and A+B (with the pre dummies being omitted), and the three interactions between post and group (which are the DID parameters of interest)? If you're doing this in a fixed-effects framework, the time-invariant group dummies will drop out, but you care about the interaction coefficients here.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, I could also do like you said. In fact, I'm using a fixed effect model in my application, but I omitted the FE for simplicity. But the question about the Back-of-the-envelope remains. Should I use the option 1 or 2 to find the overall effect of the policies? I'm think that Option 2 is the correct one, but I would like to confirm it with someone.